# MyFirstApp android tutorial error on DisplayMessageActivity.java

Tags: android, textview

I been following it and i am stuck on 3 textview errors
tutorial:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
I get 2 error saying textView cannot be resolved and one saying textView cannot be resolved as a variable. help!

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared it as `textview` (lowercase "v") but are referencing it as `textView` (uppercase "v"). Pick one!

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this); // Change the "v" to uppercase
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Variables in Java are case sensitive](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/casesensitive.htm), so `textView` and `textview` are different. Change your code to this:

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setTextSize(40);
textview.setText(message);

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textview);
```

Comment: That's bad.  I saw your first answer, now edited to copy Ken Wolf.  Not good behaviour on SO.